# Custom link to redirect to another link

Tags: php, html

I have a situation here. I want one link to redirect to another link. I am using it in custom php project.

```
 www.xyz.net/?ref=admin
```

to REDIRECT to registration page

```
 www.xyz.net/user/register?ref=admin
```

admin could be replaced by any other name.

Comment: So what's your question? And before you say, "how do I do it?", remember that questions like that are too broad and will be closed as such. So if you've written any code thus far I highly recommend adding it to your question. You should read "[how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: I have clearly mention my problem sir. i want to redirect a url. @JohnConde

Comment: Looks like you need to learn more about what is expected of users here. You're expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: write this **window.location = "www.example.com";** to your index.html file

Comment: @AnuragAwasthi That will redirect *all* page requests to that URL. I can't imagine that's what they want.

Comment: these link are for referrers... referrers link should only redirect to register page

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this. Sorry I haven't time for check.

```
if(!empty($_GET['ref'])){
  $ref = $_GET['ref'];
  header("Location: http://example.net/user/register?ref=$ref");
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sonam ..it worked